# Increasing functions are Baire one

Tags: real-analysis

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$ 
Let $f: \R \to \R$ be an increasing function. $(a \leq b \Rightarrow f(a) \leq f(b))$. I want to prove that $f \in \mathcal B$, the Baire one functions.

I first tried to prove that $g(x) := \lfloor f(x)+x \rfloor$ is in $\mathcal B$. The points of discontinuity of $g$ are countable since $g$ is increasing. Now, let $\mathcal D$ be the points in $\R$ where $g$ is not continuous. If $z \in \mathcal D$ then I want to prove that $\exists \delta > 0: (z-\delta,z+\delta) \cap \mathcal D = \{z\}$, i.e. $z$ is the only discontinuity in a certain neighborhood. Then it is not hard to prove that $g \in \mathcal B$ and that $f$ is the uniform limit of $\mathcal B$ functions and thus is also $\mathcal B$.

I already tried to prove this (existence of $\delta > 0$) by contradiction. However, I could not see a nice way to get here a contradiction.

Comment: For those of us who have forgotten the terminology, "Baire one" means what? Only countably many discontinuities, the set of discontinuities is of the first category, or what?

Comment: Sorry. Baire one functions are the pointwise limit of continuous functions.

Comment: Let $D(f)$ be the set of points at which $f$ is discontinuous; you’re trying to show that $D(f)$ is always a discrete subset of $\Bbb R$. Unfortunately, this need not be true. For an extreme example, let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and define $$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\sum_{q_n<x}\frac1{2^n}\;;$$ then $f$ is a strictly increasing function, and $D(f)=\Bbb Q$. (I’ll have to think a bit about how you might actually prove it.)

Comment: I was thinking about the discontinuities of $g$. I.e. if $g$ has a discontinuity $z$ which is a limit of other discontinuities of $g$ then $g$ has to be unbounded ?! around $z$ ?

Answer (score 5):

I explained in a comment why your approach cannot work; here’s a start on one that does.

Let $D_d$ be the set of points at which the monotonically increasing function $f$ is discontinuous, let $D_c$ be a countable dense subset of $\Bbb R\setminus D_d$, and let $D=D_d\cup D_c$. Note that we may assume that $n,-n\in D$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. (Why?) $D$ is countably infinite, so we can enumerate it as $D=\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $D_n=\{x_k:k\le n\}$.

For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ there is an $m_n\in\Bbb N$ such that $n,-n\in D_{m_n}$ and for each $x\in[-n,n]$ there is an $x_k\in D_{n_m}$ such that $|x-x_k|<\frac1{2^n}$. (Why?) We may further assume that $m_{n+1}>m_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Let $E_n=D_{m_n}\cap[-n,n]$; we can enumerate $E_n=\{y_k^{(n)}:0\le k\le e_n\}$, where $e_n=|E_n|-1$, in such a way that $$-n=y_0^{(n)}<y_1^{(n)}<\ldots<y_{e_n-1}^{(n)}<y_{e_n}^{(n)}=n\;.$$

Let $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be defined as follows:

- $f_n(x)=f(-n)$ if $x\le -n$;
- $f_n(x)=f(n)$ if $x\ge n$;
- $f_n\left(y_k^{(n)}\right)=f\left(y_k^{(n)}\right)$ for $k=0,\ldots,e_n$; and
- $f_n$ is linear on each interval $\left[y_k^{(n)},y_{k+1}^{(n)}\right]$ for $k=0,\ldots,e_n-1$.

Clearly $f_n$ is continuous. Show that $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges pointwise to $f$.

Comment: The reason you gave for the edit you made 30 minutes ago reminded me of [this Academia SE comment of mine](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/195412/i-keep-making-excessive-silly-mistakes-i-just-caught-another-one-right-before-g/195413#comment530202_195413).