# Baire class one function in terms $\varepsilon-\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540241/increasing-functions-are-baire-one) @Brian M. Scott has proved that a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=\sum_{q_n\leq x} \frac{1}{2^n}$, where $\mathbb{Q} =\{q_1, q_2, \cdots\}$, is Baire one.

In this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-08/S0002-9939-00-05826-3/S0002-9939-00-05826-3.pdf) has proved that $f$ is Baire one iff for any $\varepsilon$, there is a positive function $\delta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^+$ so that if $|x-y|<\delta(x) \wedge\delta(y)$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$.

My question: How to show that $f$ is Baire one using $\varepsilon-\delta$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Bbb Q=\{q_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals, and let

$$f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\sum_{q_n\le x}\frac1{2^n}\;.$$

Note that if $x>y$, then

$$|f(x)-f(y)|=f(x)-f(y)=\sum_{y<q_n\le x}\frac1{2^n}\;.$$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, and fix $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $2^{-n}<\epsilon$. For each $x\in\Bbb R$ let

$$\delta(x)=\min\{|x-q_k|:k\le n\text{ and }q_k\ne x\}\;.$$

Suppose that $x,y\in\Bbb R$, and $|x-y|<\min\{\delta(x),\delta(y)\}$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $x>y$. If $k\le n$, then $q_k\notin(y,y+\delta(y))\supseteq(y,x]$, so

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le\sum_{k>n}\frac1{2^k}=\frac1{2^n}<\epsilon\;.$$